GitHub Workflow Trigger Conditions in Monorepo for changes on Specific Paths
I have a Monorepo with the following folder structure:
apps/
  |--app1/
  |--app2/
  :
  :
  |--app9/

Currently, my workflow triggers on every commit to the main branch, which is protected and requires PR reviews. Periodically, we run a semantic workflow that creates tags and releases.
While the current setup functions well, I prefer to refine it so that workflows trigger only when specific paths undergo changes. For instance, if app1 and app5 are modified, their respective jobs should run to deploy the application.
I can accomplish this easily using actions such as Paths-Filter and Changed-Files, particularly on the Main branch. However, I desire the same functionality in our production environment, which operates with semantic versioning. This complicates identifying changes and their corresponding paths on the releases/tags.
Although I could use git diff or other methods to achieve this, I prefer a streamlined workflow with minimal workarounds.
I would appreciate any suggestions or best practices for handling this scenario.
Additionally, if this question has been addressed elsewhere online, please feel free to share relevant links.

However, I desire the same functionality in our production environment, which operates with semantic versioning. Could you share more details regarding how this workflow would operate? (trigger, configs, and so on...)

I trigger the Semantic Workflow manually, which creates the release and a tag based on the commit messages on the main branch.

Ok, based on this create release/tag trigger alone, there is no streamline configuration to get paths/files updated, without using a git diff or one of those path-filter / changed-files action. Therefore, you would need to implement a customizable solution here.
